# FIrebase hosting rewrites configuration for complex requests/links

Tags: reactjs, firebase, router, firebase-hosting

I have a question about rewrites on firebase hosting with react app which uses routing
Currently my rewrites at firebase.json file looks like this:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }]
```

It works for direct requests like:

sampleDomain.com/about

react app display proper /about site

but when i try to direct load for example mydomain.com/user/userId/post

it give me blank page, on localhost it works

i have tried to add to rewrites another position like:

```
{
        "source": "/user/**/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
```

Still when i open in browser mydomain.com/user/userId/post
it gives blank page.

maybe someone has similar case

Comment: `"/user/**"` will match any file or folder under user so I would guess that it's matching but your page is having errors when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```html
<base href="/" />
```

inside

```html
 <head>
```

resolved the problem